# Test Failure: ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is in my _line_items.text.erb file:

```
<%= sprintf("%2d x %s", line_item.quantity,
              truncate(line_item.product.title, length: 50)) %>
```

orders.yml

```
one:
  name: Dave Thomas
  address: MyText
  email: dave@example.org 
  pay_type: Check
```

line_items.yml

```
one:
  product: ruby
  cart_id: 1
  order: one

two:
  product_id: 1
  cart_id: 1
  order: one
```

products.yml

```
ruby:
  title: Programming Ruby 1.9 
  description: 
    Ruby is the fastest growing and most exciting dynamic language out there. 
    If you need to get working programsdelivered fast, you should add Ruby to your toolbox.
  price: 49.50 
  image_url: ruby.png
```

This all seems to be correct.

Here is the actual test:

```
class OrderNotifierTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  test "received" do
    mail = OrderNotifier.received(orders(:one))
    assert_equal "Pragmatic Store Order Confirmation", mail.subject
    assert_equal ["dave@example.org"], mail.to
    assert_equal ["depot@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match  /1 x Programming Ruby 1.9/, mail.body.encoded
  end
```

Any ideas on where else to look for the `ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass` error?

Update:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id, :quantity, :order_id, :product, :cart, :price
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product

  def total_price 
    self.price * self.quantity
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you specify the names for your fixture files correctly? I mean `order` and `product` don't have the `s` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, jdoe. That wasn't the issue, and were just typos in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just what the error says, you are trying to call an undefined method `title` on an object of type `NilClass`. If you look at the line of code you've provided, you should be able to see where the error lies:

```
<%= sprintf("%2d x %s", line_item.quantity,
          truncate(line_item.product.title, length: 50)) %>
```

The portion that reads `line_item.product.title` is where the problem is.  the `product` item must be nil.  I would recommend changing it to `line_item.product.try(:title)`, which will take advantage of [Rails's try helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try), and prevent a nil error from being thrown in the event that `product` is nil.

It looks like your fixtures aren't written properly.  `line_item` # 2 is the one that has a problem... You need to change line_item #2 to say product: ruby instead of product_id: 1. That should fix it. As stated in the fixture docs (see below).

Looks like you also need to define the fixtures as being accessible in your test like so:

```
class OrderNotifierTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  fixtures :orders, :line_items, :products
  ...
```

See [rails fixture docs](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/Fixtures.html) for more info.  (specifically the section titled 'Using Fixtures'.)

Comment: But this in my tests, so the product should *never* be nil. I can't figure out why it is. I feel like try is the wrong approach, or am I missing something?

Comment: I changed it to back to `product_id: 1`, although, that didn't fix it. Same error.

Comment: I've updated the original question to include the line_item model.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you should remove `:order`, `:product`, and `:cart` from your `attr_accessible` list.  Rails will automatically make them available.  Also you didn't define the fixtures as being available.  See my updated post above.

Comment: Doing so creates errors in my testing: `3) Error: test_should_get_new(OrdersControllerTest):
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: cart, product, price` Is there another way to make the test pass that is a better solution and/or approach?

Comment: That's because you're fixtures are messed up.  The 2nd one specifically.  Read the fixture documentation.  I retract what I said earlier (sorry I haven't used fixtures much).  You need to change line_item #2 to say `product: ruby` instead of `product_id: 1`.  That should fix it.

Comment: I was getting the error twice, but changing the #2 line_item fixed one of them. I'll dig deeper into why the other one is popping up. That didn't fix the MassAssignment Issue though.

Comment: Yea you may need to add them back to the `attr_accessible`.  I normally build my relationships by doing stuff like `cart.line_items = LineItem.new(attrs)`, etc... but it looks like the fixtures do it differently.

Comment: Okay, then you got me (mostly) straightened out!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I solved it by clearing the database.

Perhaps you already had data in the database that were no longer relevant after you added the "Order" table (or a separate "PayType" table instead of the "pay_type" field in the "Order" table). You need to empty the cart or clear the database.

You can also solve this problem in another way, if you don't want to clear the database.

Add `if line_item.product`

```
<%= sprintf("%2d x %s", line_item.quantity,
      truncate(line_item.product.title, length: 50) if line_item.product) %>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `%>`